# Oracle Forms 10g in Desktop Mode

Tags: oracleforms

Can I have an installation / support of Running Oracle Forms 10g in Desktop Mode?

Is it supported?

I would like to Run Oracle Forms 10g Just like we can run normal Java application in standalone mode.

Thanks , Niraj Salot.